# Predicting ctree with R

Tags: r, prediction

I'm new to R and I'm trying to predict by date with `ctree` using R.
My data is like this:

```
Datos      | Global_active_power
2006-12-16 | 3.0534747
2006-12-17 | 2.3544861
And like this 1433 entries.
```

Here is the code:

```
data <- read.table('diena.txt', sep = ' ')
library("party")
set.seed(124)
datos <- as.Date(data$Datos)
View(data[2])
train <- data[1:sum(datos<"2009-12-16"),]
test <- data[-(1:sum(datos<"2009-12-16")),]
View(train)
dt <- ctree(test$Global_active_power ~ test$Datos, data=train,controls=ctree_control(maxdepth=3))
p <- predict(dt, test)
View(p)
```

Using `View(p)`, R is giving me same number in all rows. 
I don't know if it is right way to predict. Maybe anyone can help.

And for the future maybe anyone know how to predict future values like my Date end in 2010-11-30 and i want to predict what will be in 2011.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a technical issue. You should really use the specification

```
Global_active_power ~ Datos, data = train
```

instead of

```
test$Global_active_power ~ test$Datos, data = train
```

The former will take the variables from the `train` data set whereas the latter will always take the variables from the `test` data set. In general using `data$...` constructs in model formulas is almost always a bad idea - especially when predictions on new data are of interest.

Second, and more seriously, there is a conceptual problem. If you use a model like `power ~ date` this specifies essentially a trend model. In case of a regression tree, you approximate the nonlinear trend by a step function. Predicting with a step function *outside* the range of the training data, will always result in a constant fitted value.

But also with other nonlinear trend specifications (e.g., a GAM) you will almost surely get poor results outside the training data. Everything else would be very surprising.

I would recommend to look into time series models instead to see whether you can use those for power forecasting.

Answer (score 1):

The preidct() on ctree object returns a list and not a dataframe. It has to be unlisted and converted to a dataframe for further usage.

```
a=data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(p)){
  a= rbind(a,unlist(p[i]))
}
colnames(a)= c(0,1)
```

Its a late reply,but hope it helps someone in the future.